# Studio Controls "Auto connect port" disabled

Tags: ubuntu-studio, jack

I used [Ubuntu Studio Installer](https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer/) on top of Kubuntu 20.04. After that, I added the [Ubuntu Studio Backports PPA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/BackportsPPA). That got rid of **ubuntustudio-controls** and replaced it with **studio-controls**. This is my version of that:
[image]

I asked about the Auto Connect feature some months ago here and since then I have updated to the latest Studio Controls (at the moment, `2.0.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.1`).

My problem now is that the Auto Connect Port option is disabled. I don't know exactly why is that or what config should I check. Does anyone know why is it disabled?

[image]

I am forced to launch Carla and connect manually as shown here, which is a bit of a pain, to be honest :)

[image]

My problem back in the day was that it defaulted to "system:playback_" but now not even that, I just plainly cannot use it.

Thanks

Comment: I also wonder why jack status is "unknown". What happens if you click on `Add an input Bridge`?

Comment: Yeah, that's another good one but less critical to me... If I click that button it just adds a pulse_in-1 but that is of no use to me

Comment: I cannot find your version of ubuntustudio-controls, not even in any backport ppa. Where did you get this version of ubuntustudio-controls? Which version of Ubuntu are running? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1295655/edit) your question to add this relevant details.

Comment: I'd consider this as a bug, I just installed the thing and on my screen it's exact the same, jackstatus is also unknown and with the input bridges I can't do anything useful.

Comment: The truth is, it might be a bug specific to my HW since I just installed the new Ubuntu Studio 20.10 to try with a cleaner install and I got the exact same thing; Auto Connect Port disabled and Jack Status unknown...

Comment: For me it works fine in UbuntuStudio 20.10 (not upgraded, fresh install).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, the problem (Auto-connect disabled and Jack Status *Unknown*) went away when updated studio-controls to 2.1.0 version